# Opportunity Closed Won - Change in ownership

Tags: process-builder

We have a created renewal opportunity creation using process builder along with immediate actions of emails and tasks.

In our sales process, we have created One custom stage before the closed-won stage and i.e., "Order received from Customer" at 100%

As per the process, Account Manager saves opportunity record at "Order received from Customer" stage 100%.

Finance team who will process "Order received from Customer" stage related documents and then they change stage to "Closed-Won" and save the record.

The problem I am facing here is

Renewal Opportunity ownership and related emails and tasks ownership is changing from Account Manager to Finance Manager.

How can i prevent the change from occurring? Account manager should retain ownership of renewal opportunity as well its tasks and emails.

should i any criteria in process builder to prevent this happening?

Thanks
Prashant

Update1: I am not able to copy paste image, so below is criteria.

Conditions are Met:

Set Conditions: 
Opportunitystage Equals Picklist = Closed Won

Conditions:
All of the conditions are met (AND)

Advanced: 
Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?

I unchecked, this advanced option

Create Record

Field Values:

AccountID: fieldreference =  Opportinity.AccountID

Comment: What are the criteria for your process?

Comment: Please add information in an edit to your question, not as comments.

Comment: i have updated the post with criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Your Process Builder is configured to run and create your renewal opportunities when the stage reaches Closed Won. Because your Finance Manager is making that change, they are the running user of the process when it executes. As a result, they own any records it creates that are not otherwise assigned.

Two options present themselves:

1. Change your Process to fire on "Order received from Customer" stage, so that your Account Manager will be the running user.
2. Change the field values that you populate when you create the renewal opportunity and its linked objects to explicitly assign ownership to the Account Manager.

Option 1 is the simple and more elegant solution if it is compatible with your business requirements.

Comment: David, thanks a ton!, I will discuss this change with finance and sales, but in meantime, is there any validation rule which prevents such a change? Also as a best practice should a validation rule be written at all? Just thinking Thanks

Comment: No, validation rules won't help you here - it's really just about keeping track of the context user, or being explicit about assigning ownership. However, if your process is sending out emails that get recorded in the database, you may not be able to explicitly assign their ownership, so changing the running user to Account Manager might be the only real solution.

Comment: So if I add Field value such as OwnerID field-reference OpportnityOwnerID, this should work right?

Comment: Sure thing! And the same for Tasks or anything else you create. Bear in mind that your created by/last modified by fields will still show the Finance Manager, though.

Comment: Hi David, 

I created field value: Account Manager Field reference Opportunity.OwnerID, the process did not throw any error but the output is still the same, i.e., the finance manager is inheriting the ownership of renewal opportunity.

For now, I will try to convince sales and finance teams about creating renewal opp at "order received from customer", if this fails I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Prashant